# How to see source for IOError in python?

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

I am using `Pydev` to do Python development using Eclipse.

Control clicking any module name in my source (such as `traceback` or `subprocess`) opens up its source code in another window.

However when I control click `IOError` pydev doesn't show me the source?

Why is this?
Which module IOError comes from and why isn't its source available?

Edit:

Though the original question is answered, the reason why I wanted to see the source was to see what values `IOError.errno` can take. For example and `errno` is `2` - I believe - when file could not be found. I want to see all other possibilities.

How can I do that?

Comment: I think that it's because it lives in [`exceptions.c`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/5609135c6e86/Objects/exceptions.c) ;-)

Comment: As mgilson stated, it's directly implemented in C, not in Python.

Comment: Generally, IDE's locate the file based on the `__file__` attribute, which `IOError` doesn't have.

Comment: @mgilson, class object does not have `__file__` attribute, but module object. `exceptions` module does not have `__file__` attribute anyway.

Comment: @KshitizSharma -- If that looks like python to you, then you need to work on your python a bit.  Notice all the curly braces -- And they didn't use `from __future__ import braces` at the top. ;-)

Comment: @KshitizSharma -- take a look at the `errno` module.  Specifially, [`errno.ENOENT`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/errno.html#errno.ENOENT) has a value of 2 on my computer ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a built-in exception type and defined in the module `exceptions`:

http://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#module-exceptions

It's built-in (probably all definitions are in the C-implementation?).

For other modules, you can find the file where they were loaded from via:

```
>>> import httplib
>>> httplib.__file__ 
'C:\\Python27\\lib\\httplib.pyc'
```

But for module exception, you get:

```
>>> import exceptions
>>> exceptions.__file__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__file__'
```